# How to copy and run command in different terminal

Tags: c++, terminal, xterm, gnome-terminal

I have a simple program, e.g. in C++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b;
    c = a + b;
    cout << c;
}
```

Here i need to give `a` and `b` as inputs at the time of execution.

I need to write a script to auto type value of a (say 5) and b (say 7) into the first terminal.

Comment: read up on piping and the `echo` command

Comment: Have you considered writing your script to *launch* the program itself and then just interact directly with it instead of trying to work with multiple terminals?

Comment: Another simpler recommendation would be to have your C++ program accept command-line arguments so that your script can call it with any desired inputs (e.g. `./your-program.out 5 7`). Your C++ program would just need to convert the input number strings into actual numbers (see `atoi` function)

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and upvote + accept the answer that you found most helpful. It helps everyone in the community.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change something to do so, as you want to pass the arguments from the script. 
C++ program `main.cpp:`

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  if(argc==1)
   {
    exit(1);
   }
  int a=atoi(argv[1]);
   int b=atoi(argv[2]);
  cout<<a+b<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

and shell script will be :

```
 #!/bin/bash

    g++ temp.cpp -o out
    a=5
    b=2
    ./out "${a}" "${b}"
```

You should see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258682/how-to-read-variables-in-bash-and-pass-these-variables-to-a-c-program-as-argum) for passing variables.And see [this also](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/)

Comment: I guess I should've refreshed the page... I noticed your response after posting mine and we ended up thinking along the same lines :\

Comment: @ray I can't think how both code are same. but if you see answered time it solves.

Comment: No, it's just that we proposed similar solutions. Our code is certainly not the same, and I hadn't seen your post prior to mine. But we still provided similar solutions to the same problem. We should just both feel good about it.

Comment: what if i want to pass an array ?? a[0]=5 ,a[1]=2 ,? will that work ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to write a program that interacts with multiple terminals or works with pipes, which might be more complicated, I'd recommend making your program *simpler* by having it handle command-line arguments. You can re-write your C++ program as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>    // for atoi function

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])  // to accept CLI inputs
{
    // argv[0] has path/name to this program
    // argv[1] has 1st argument, if provided
    // argv[2] has 2nd argument, if provided
    // if argc != 3, then we don't have everything we expected, and we bail
    if(argc != 3) {
        cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " arg1 arg2" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // for simplicity, we assume that you won't get letters, only numbers
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    cout << (a + b);

    return 0;
}
```

You can then write a simple shell script to launch your program with whatever arguments you want. For example, if your built program is called `test` (use `g++ -o test test.cpp` to build), then you can use this example `launcher.bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..10}
do
    ./test $i $i
    echo
done
```

The script produces the following output:

```
/tmp ❯ ./launcher.bash
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Answer (score 0):

If the executable is **a.out** then you can use

`a=5;b=7;echo $a $b | ./a.out`

Btw, in your example the *namespace* for *cout*/*cin* is missing (for e.g. add `using namespace std;` after the **#include**).